# manually adding terms to nodes directly from db

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have lots of nodes in my system. I want to add them some taxonomy terms.

I have a CSV file for each term, and in this file I have the list of node id's. Example:

apples.csv:

5
9
12
24
....
....

SO I need node 5, 9, 12 and 24 to have the term "apples".

I wrote a php script to directly add that term to each of the nodes. That script populates the table "field_data_field_category" correctly.

I can also see the term on the node page.

The problem is the nodes dont appear in the term page. Also if I create a view to display nodes of specific term, it becomes empty.

Is there another table to keep the node - term relationship?

EDIT:

I just found that there is another table keeping the relationship between node and term: taxonomy_index: "Maintains denormalized information about node/term..."

How does this table populated? On a cron run? Because I see some of my node - term pairs there. Some not.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to update all your nodes with new terms.

Comment: thanks but my csv doesnt contain all the information of nodes. so i cannot match nodes on my system with the ones on the csv.

Comment: but you sad "in this file I have the list of node id's". This is enough to update nodes. just add term name to each of this ids.

Comment: first export nodes.

Comment: I dont know how to mark a node with a term that must be taken from the filename. As I said, I have to get the term name from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

From the Views query output, I see:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.sticky AS node_sticky, 'node' AS field_data_field_based_on_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.nid IN  (SELECT tn.nid AS nid
FROM 
{taxonomy_index} tn
```

I see views is using taxonomy_index table, so I ended up populating this table also. Here is my code if anyone is interested: